# emails sent with php mail don't show up correctly in outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook, header

I'm working on a site that was recently moved. After the move all the scripts that use the php mail() function **AND** have MIME-Version: and Content-type in the header fail to display correctly. They show up like this

```
Delivered-To: asdf@adffdsf.com Received: by 10.114.121.18 with SMTP id t17cs128223wac;
        Thu, 19 Nov 2009 11:52:35 -0800 (PST) Received: by 10.231.48.150 with SMTP id s22mr755195ibfdge.22.1258660355109;
        Thu, 19 Nov 2009 11:52:35 -0800 (PST) Return-Path: <anonymous@u15366254sdf.onlinehome-server.com> Received: from u15366254.onlinehome-server.com (u15366254.onlinehome-server.com [74.208.194.179])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 16si2425376iwn.129.2009.11.19.11.52.34;
        Thu, 19 Nov 2009 11:52:34 -0800 (PST) Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of anonymous@u15366254.onlinehome-server.com designates 74.208.194.179 as permitted sender) client-ip=74.208.194.179; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of anonymous@u15366254.onlinehome-server.com designates 74.208.194.179 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=anonymous@u15386254.onlinehome-server.com Received: (qmail 8341 invoked by uid 48); 19 Nov 2009 08:55:35 -0500 Date: 19 Nov 2009 08:55:35 -0500 
Message-ID: <20091119185535.8339.qmail@u15386254.onlinehome-server.com> 
To: asdf@asdfad.com 
Subject: Retailer Application MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
From: asdf@asdfad.com
```

In addition the html in the message shows up raw.

When I use the exact same script to send an email on another server it works as expected. Also the email scripts on the site that use Swift mail work fine.

I could just modify them to use swift but there are many scripts that would have to be edited.

I'm using php 5.1.6.

Any ideas?

Comment: would you be able to show us the PHP code to generate that mail ?

Comment: +1 to RageZ.  Without the code, no one can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related with `\n` and `QMAIL`, the mail function documentation state this.

> Note: If messages are not received,
>   try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor
>   quality Unix mail transfer agents
>   replace LF by CRLF automatically
>   (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is
>   used). This should be a last resort,
>   as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.

so you if you header are separated by `\r\n` you could probably replace those by single `\n`.

This [bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15841) report also provide a solution using a script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where an email sent through PHP showed up as the raw email content in Outlook (other clients had no problem).  Turns out the reason for my problem was something else entirely from what was accepted here, so I'm assuming there's a lot of ways problems in the header can cause Outlook to just give up on rendering it.

I was sending a few emails as BCC with a 'To' header that didn't look like a real email (it was something like 'Example Group' instead of 'Example Group ') -- as soon as I made sure the 'To' header was actually formatted like an email address, it showed up in Outlook without any issues.