# PHP Mail() sent to Outlook breaks code

Tags: php, email, outlook, gmail

I've looked around here but could not find an answer regarding the problem that I am facing.

Most similar to my problems are in this: [emails sent with php mail don't show up correctly in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768016/emails-sent-with-php-mail-dont-show-up-correctly-in-outlook) , but I checked and the solution did not work for me.

I am basically writing a PHP script that sends out emails, with a table in it. The problem however, is that if I receive it in gmail, the email shows up fine, but it does not even come through to Outlook at all.

Examining the source code of emails that do make it through to Outlook, shows a line break for some reason (again not present in gmail)

Eg:

```
<td>  xyz@aaa
tt.com </td>
```

When it should show up as:

```
<td>  xyz@aaatt.com </td>
```

In my php code, I even try to remove the line returns and spaces (as there should be no spaces in emails)

```
$rmv = array("\n");
$lead_email = str_replace($rmv, "", $lead_email);

$rmv = array("\r");
$lead_email = str_replace($rmv, "", $lead_email);

$rmv = array(" ");
$lead_email = str_replace($rmv, "", $lead_email);
```

For reference, my mail header is as follows:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers .= 'From: helpdesk@viatechcrm.com' . "\n";
```

Btw should I use iso-8859-1 or utf-8? I occasionally encounter names with European characters.

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: So I was examining the source code, and found something interesting. The message is really long, but it only shows 3-4 lines. I found that it gets cut off right about 991 characters, thus the email breaking up.. Is this something to do with the Mime-Version 1.0?
How can I increase the number of characters it can receive? I tried adding '\r\n' after every table row, but one of the 4 emails still does not show up for some reason

**EDIT 2**: Thanks everyone for the help! I finally figured it out, in a forum post dated back in 2009. For future reference, refer to the last posting:

http://forums.devarticles.com/php-development-48/formatting-a-newline-line-break-in-php-html-output-5274.html

Comment: Use a library such as Swiftmailer, rather than mail() - it'll get all the intricacies right for you.

Comment: Use carriage return with line feed for Windows (Outlook) \r\n

Comment: Yup . outlook does not handle html correctly at all for most cases. i think it is because it is using ms word go render the htmls.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UTF-8 if you have non-alphanumeric characters. You should end each header line with a "\r\n", not just a plain "\n". Not sure if this will fix your problem as I can't test, but it is something that you should fix nontheless.

Comment: Hi, I tried setting 'charset=utf-8' and adding "\r\n" but 1 out of 4 emails still does not show up.

Comment: maybe it gets caught by Outlook's spam filter? you should check this.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too, it is not in the Spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have only added "\r\n" to the HTML part of your message. **All** header lines must end in "\r\n", not just the lines in the body. Some clients and servers will cope with just "\n" but they really don't have to (see [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)), hence the inconsistencies between Gmail and Outlook.